# How to use Powershell DSC for application installation?

Tags: powershell, puppet, devops, dsc

Currently we are having application which will be in DVD. there will be setup.exe and user will click on that and fill the inputs it asks for . Inputs such as path where the application to be installed, SQL server instance where db will be created and port numbers which required to be bind.

I am hearing that Powershell DSC can be used for application deployment. But it is not like running some setup.exe and get some inputs for installation.

Whether Powershell DSC can really be used for application deployment? or is it only for environment preparation?
If it is being used for application deployment , how it is being achieved? Whether the end user told to fill the data in some configurationdata psd1 file manually and then run the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Package resource. However you may want to explore looking at [cChoco](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/cChoco) instead as [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) is much more geared towards software management (application deployment) with handling installs, upgrades and uninstallation.

https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/cChoco

Answer (score 0):

Powershell DSC its for Application Deployment, but... you can use it as an exe, what you can do is create a simple console or windows forms EXE program that embeds the script as a resource and the EXE, upon loading retrieves the script and throws it at a PowerShell runspace to execute.

This is a link about it [Make PSexe](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/)